# richtextbox - buttons - cursor issue - don't know how to title it

Tags: winforms, button, cursor, richtextbox

Big problem with my program!

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3564/9lsazq3e_png.htm

If i click the richTextBox i want to fill it with the numbers on the buttons.

how i do it now ---> (each Button has this click event)

```
private void digits_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Control)
        {
            rtxtLast.Text += (sender as Control).Text;
            rtxtLast.SelectionStart = rtxtLast.Text.Length;
            rtxtLast.Focus();
        }
    }
```

I can fill the richTextBox with with the digits but only at the end of the text.

**but i'd like to insert the the text at the cursor**

for the cursor i have the left/right arrows (or by touching on the display)

btw i have a full touch system so i have to work with buttons ( i have no keyboard / mouse )

its also the same problem with the spacebar ("Leertaste")

```
        private void button36_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtxtLast.Text += " ";
        rtxtLast.SelectionStart = rtxtLast.Text.Length;
        rtxtLast.Focus();
    }
```

This is how i delete ("Löschen")

```
        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rtxtLast.SelectionStart > 0)
        {
            int index = rtxtLast.SelectionStart;
            rtxtLast.Text = rtxtLast.Text.Remove(rtxtLast.SelectionStart - 1, 1);
            rtxtLast.Select(index - 1, 1);
            rtxtLast.Focus();
        }
        else if (rtxtLast.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            rtxtLast.Text = rtxtLast.Text.Remove(rtxtLast.Text.Length - 1);
        }
    }
```

and this for left and right

```
    private void left2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rtxtLast.SelectionStart > 0)
        {
            int index = rtxtLast.SelectionStart;
            rtxtLast.Select(index - 1, 1);
            rtxtLast.Focus();
        }
    }


    private void right2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rtxtLast.SelectionStart > -1)
        {
            int index = rtxtLast.SelectionStart;
            rtxtLast.Select(index + 1, 1);
            rtxtLast.Focus();
        }
    }
```

left/right and delete is working 
but i have not found a solution for the digits ..

i know the code is wrong but i have no clue how to do it right

is there anybody who could help me?

greetz
Artur

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);
```

Each time you want to send a character with a button click

```
private void Button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Focus();

        SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, 0x100, 0x30, 0);
        SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, 0x102, 0x30, 0);
    }
```

*0x30* is the `0` virtual key. *0x100, 0x102* are `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_CHAR` messages.
You can send all keybord keys using this method. Another example the `backspace key`:

```
private void buttonBackSpace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Focus();

        SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, 0x100, 0x8, 0); //0x8 is the backspace virtual key
        SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, 0x102, 0x8, 0);
    }
```

For a list of virtualkeys codes [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

valter

Comment: hmm i tried this .. my windows form is freezing .. where do i have to put the [DLLImport.....] part?

Comment: NOPE everything is working now .. perfect thanks .. you made my day =)